# Function with bool return value, only set 1 byte of the entire register

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

I have the following piece of code which is a part of api (cdecl). In MSVC++ the sizeof bool is 1 byte, but since bool is implementation defined, some programs compiled by other compiler/the author incorrectly define function signature may treat bool as >1 byte and calling the check below may return true on their side of programs.

```
virtual bool isValid()
{
    return false;
    // ^ code above in asm: xor al, al
}
```

To avoid this, I put an inline asm, `xor eax, eax` before the return - but I feel it a bit hacky and it of course will not work on x64 due to lack of inline assembler support.

Using `#define bool int` will work but it is not I wanted, as I have structs that have bool datatype inside it and using this will causes corruption.

Is there anything like intrinsics that can zeroed the eax/rax register or anything that can solve this problem?

Comment: Two libraries produced by different compilers attempt to communicate using implementation-defined features. Do you see anything wrong with this picture?

Comment: It might be a surprise for you, but size of almost any fundamental type is implementation-defined. `int` is no different from `bool` in this regard.

Comment: It supposed to be only msvc++, but you know what will happen when you add plugin support. The particular programs use a signature of 4 byte on x86, so in this case returning as `int` should work.

Comment: If you want to exchange binary data between modules compiled by different compilers, possibly using different ABI's, that's going to be very hard and painful, but a good start is to use [fixed-size integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) instead of arbitrary sized types. A good way to continue is to not use C++ features at all, because that's will most likely not work out at all, and instead use a plain C interface with only fixed-sized C compatible data types..

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, it deserves an upvote since it's not obvious how deep the potential incompatibilities go.

Comment: For additional information, the api has only one exports, which is factory function and returns a COM-like interface, pure virtual - it not cdecl actually but __thiscall, however return value still on eax. At the time I made it, I realize the problem with integers so all variables has fixed-size integers. However its funny that I didn't think of bool datatype. There are hundreds of interface with many members that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing that will do what you're asking for. Your problem needs a much different solution.

First any code that "incorrectly define function signature" is broken an needs to fixed. It's never the solution to work around it in other code.

Next your problem is like more than just `bool` being implementation defined, the C++ standard makes a whole host of things are implementation defined. So much so that two different C++ compilers are rarely have a compatible ABIs. If your code provides C++ interfaces for the use of code compiled by other people you'll probably need to produce separately compiled binaries, whether in the form of object files, static libraries, DLLs or executables, for each different compiler you want to support. In fact you may need to provide separate binaries for each version of each compiler.

There are two C++ compilers the try to be compatible with the Microsoft C++ ABI. The first is [Intel's C++ compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/512818) and the second is [the Windows port of clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html). The clang implementation is notably still a work in progress. You may still need to create separate versions for each version of the Microsoft C/C++ runtime libraries your code is compiled with.

You can potentially reduce the number of different versions of binaries that you need to distribute by providing a pure C interface to your code. A pure C interface means using only C data types and only functions declared as `extern "C"`. While things like classes, member functions, templates, RTTI and exceptions can be used in your implementation the can't be used as part of your public interface. An exception are COM-like interfaces, classes with nothing but public pure virtual functions. Since C compilers for Windows all use essentially the same C ABI and support COM interfaces, compatibility issues are less likely to be an issue. However the `bool` type (actually the `_Bool` type in C) is probably not safe to use, since it's a relatively recent addition to the C language. Use `int` in your C interfaces instead.

Note that because of C/C++ runtime differences even if you all you want to do distribute compiled binaries for use with Microsoft's Visual C++ compiler you may still need to distribute versions for each version of the compiler. That's because each version comes with a different runtime implementation and which have data structures with incompatible internal layouts. You can't pass an STL container created in a function compiled by one version of Visual C++ to a function compiled with a different version. You can't allocate memory with `malloc` in an executable and `free` it in a DLL, if the executable and DLL use different versions of the C runtime.

Unfortunately unless you're willing to restrict your users to one particular compiler the easy solution to your problem that you're looking for may not exist. Note that this is a common solution used by programs that provide plugin support. Pugins need to be compiled the same version of the same compiler that compiled the executable.